# Validate domain name

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, ajax, validation

I have a text box where the user can enter an URL, I would like to validate the user input such as the url is in the same domain as the application (specified in web config).

i would like  to use javascript to validate this with regular expressions.

The domain name is "http://www.example.com" and user input that i m expecting is "http://www.example.com/folder".

the domain name is stored in the Webconfig AppSettings sections.

Comment: What are your JavaScript abstractions?

Comment: Could you show us what your web config specification looks like?  i.e. is is protocol://example.com/, example.com/, or example.com

Comment: "'http://www.example.com'" and the url that i m expecting from user is "http://www.example.com/folder"

Comment: Why a regular expression? You can do this with a simple (and faster) substring check.

Answer (score 2):

How about an alternative approach? Instead of asking for the full URL:

```
URL: [http://example.com/foo/bar]
```

instead ask for a relative URL and only let the user fill in the part after the host:

```
URL: http://example.com/[foo/bar]
```

(where `[xyz]` indicates the input box)

Comment: that actually sounds like a good plan.. if there is not other way then i might have to use this one.. as per requirement i need to allow the user to enter the entire url..

Answer (score 0):

Try
`location.href.match(/^http:\/\/(.+?)\//)`